# OnMessageReceived not fired if application in background

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been developing android apps for a while now and all of them have FCM integrated in them and functioning properly.

I have this app that the onMessageReceived isn't fired unless the app is opened, if the app is closed and I receive a notification it opens from splash and follows the normal flow (it doesn't go to the Notifications activity).
N.B: all the testing I've done was from the Firebase Console

I really don't know why, any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";


@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Log.wtf("RECEIVED","NOTIFICATION");

    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here. 
    Log.wtf(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.wtf(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.wtf(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }


    sendNotification("Notification");
}

private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {


    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.icon)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
}
```

Comment: please sent data payload and check in method `onMessageReceived`. If you are not sending payload then FCM will create their notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **Firebase**, you can send two type of notifications message basically.

**1. Notification messages**  : sometimes thought of as "display messages."

**2. Data/Payload messages** : which are handled by the client app.

both above Notification has different behaviour, depending upon if your app is in foreground or background.

**1.Notification msg + Background** :  delivered to the notification tray

**2.Notification msg + Foreground** :  onMessageReceived() on Android

**3.Data msg + Background** : apps receive the notification payload in the notification tray, and only handle the data payload when the user taps on the notification.

**4.Data msg + Foreground** : your app receives a message object with both payloads available.

For more clarification [check this.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)

For sending Data/payload message using FCM console use Advance option and insert key and value.

[image]

Comment: how to send data messages?

Comment: you are using firebase console right ?   there is a option to add payload in it.
add payload to your message and try.
or 
http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info/  try this link to send notifications.

Check my edited answer !!

Comment: @HusseinYassine  : let me know if this solve your problem or not ?

Comment: @PunitSharma it didn't solve mine, I have the same problem. I want the user to go to my apps google play page so it can update it, but if app is in background it just opens the app while if its in foreground it does what I want