# Disable notifications to be received only in background

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I built a chat application using firebase cloud messaging and firebase functions. But I have two problems currently. 
1. When the app is in open and a new message comes in, the app will automatically move to the main activity of the application. 
2. And secondly, I want notifications to be received only when it is in the background.

**How do I achieve this?**

Below is my onMessageReceived

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("name"), (remoteMessage.getData().get("click_action")), remoteMessage.getData().get("title"));
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {

        }
    }

    private void showNotification(String name, String click_action, String title) {
        Intent intent;

        if (click_action.equals("Download")) {
            intent = new Intent(this, Download.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        } else if (click_action.equals("Student_SystemsDevt")) {
            intent = new Intent(this, Student_SystemsDevt.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        }
        else {
            intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        }

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentText(name)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

My Manifest File

```
<application
    android:name=".GTUCONLINE"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ChoiceActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".WelcomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
    <activity
        android:name=".StudentSignUp"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LecturerSignUp"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".ProgrammeActivity" />

    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".TopicActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" />
    <activity android:name=".MIS" />
    <activity android:name=".GB" />
    <activity android:name=".FIN" />
    <activity android:name=".ENGINEERINGM" />
    <activity android:name=".BDM" />
    <activity android:name=".SCM" />
    <activity android:name=".TE" />
    <activity android:name=".TM" />
    <activity android:name=".BET" />
    <activity android:name=".ICT" />
    <activity android:name=".T" />
    <activity android:name=".IT" />
    <activity android:name=".AM" />
    <activity android:name=".OGM" />
    <activity android:name=".I" />
    <activity android:name=".PEF" />
    <activity android:name=".QM" />
    <activity android:name=".EPM" />
    <activity android:name=".PM" />
    <activity android:name=".HM" />
    <activity android:name=".StudentsList">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="StudentsList" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LecturersList" />
    <activity android:name=".AdminActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ChatActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".StudentsList" />
    <activity android:name=".LecturerMainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Download"
        android:parentActivityName=".MIS">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="Download" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MIS_Information"
        android:parentActivityName=".MIS" />
    <activity android:name=".Terms" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Admin_Login"
        android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Manipulation"
        android:parentActivityName=".Admin_Login" />
    <activity android:name=".Admins" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SystemsDevt"
        android:parentActivityName=".MIS" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SysGroupChat"
        android:parentActivityName=".SystemsDevt" />
    <activity
        android:name=".EntSystems"
        android:parentActivityName=".MIS" />
    <activity android:name=".DownloadEnt">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="DownloadEnt" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".student_mis" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Student_SystemsDevt"
        android:parentActivityName=".student_mis">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="Student_SystemsDevt" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Student_EntSys"
        android:parentActivityName=".student_mis" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SystemsDevt_Add"
        android:parentActivityName=".SystemsDevt" />
    <activity android:name=".EntSystemsAdd" />
    <activity android:name=".EntSystemsInfo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DatabaseSystems"
        android:parentActivityName=".MIS" />
    <activity android:name=".DownloadDatabaseSys" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Student_DatabaseSystems"
        android:parentActivityName=".student_mis" />
    <activity android:name=".DatabaseInfo" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DatabaseAdd"
        android:parentActivityName=".DatabaseSystems" />
    <activity
        android:name=".IntroToOil"
        android:parentActivityName=".GB" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DownloadIntro"
        android:parentActivityName=".IntroToOil" />
    <activity
        android:name=".IntroToOilInfo"
        android:parentActivityName=".IntroToOil" />
    <activity
        android:name=".IntroToOilAdd"
        android:parentActivityName=".IntroToOil" />
    <activity android:name=".student_gb" />
    <activity android:name=".StudentIntro" />
    <activity android:name=".MIS_students_new"
        android:parentActivityName=".SystemsDevt">

    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Is your App getting Data notification or simple push notification?

Comment: It's getting data notification

Comment: this answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/44455118/4919210

Answer (score 1):

1- Actually onMessageReceived is only triggered when your application is in foreground as described [enter link description here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive). So if you don't override onMessageReceived, you will not receive push when your app is in foreground

2- According to fcm docs, when your app is in background, onMessageReceived is not triggered but

> the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

It explains why your push redirects to your main activity (your launcher).

So far, you can handle the redirection from the intent.

You can also specify the activity where it sould be redirected like [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40718155/open-specific-activity-when-notification-clicked-in-fcm):

```
{
  "to":"some_device_token",
  "content_available": true,
  "notification": {
    "title": "hello",
    "body": "test message",
    "click_action": "OPEN_ACTIVITY_1"
  },
  "data": {
    "extra":"juice"
  }
}
```

don't forget intent filter for the desired activity:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="OPEN_ACTIVITY_1" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: So how do I fix the automatic redirection?

Comment: specify your activity inside "click_action" field

Comment: Currently trying that. A minute

Comment: The automatic redirection is still persistent

Comment: I am not concerned about the user clicking the notification to open a specific activity. I want to know how to fix the issue of automatic redirection when a user is in another activity. The app always redirects the user back to the main activity before even the notification pops up. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

> Also add Tasks permission in manifest.

```
private boolean isAppForeground() {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        if (appProcesses == null) {
            return false;
        }
        final String packageName = getPackageName();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
            if (appProcess.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND && appProcess.processName.equals(packageName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    } 

 if(isAppForeground()){
   // Handle notification silently without displaying in notification tray
 }else{
    // Do your regular stuff

   // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("name"), (remoteMessage.getData().get("click_action")), remoteMessage.getData().get("title"));
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {

        }
 }
```

Comment: How do I use this?

Comment: Class ForegroundCheckTask should placed outside of MyFirebaseMessagingService class and rest of code should be put into onMessageRecived()

Comment: Try now i had removed context.

Comment: I don't receive the notification alright but while I am in the app, I am redirected back to the main activity. Funny enough, that's not my launcher

Comment: how did you handle silent notification in if() condition? Because pending Intent can also be reason of jumping.

Comment: Left it blank. How do I handle the silent condition

Comment: Show me how to handle the push notification

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174378/discussion-between-arpit-bandil-and-upward-studios).